# cookie node.js express

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am trying to use cookies with express but I can't find how does it works

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    req.signedCookies.test = "aa";
    console.log(req.signedCookies.test)
    res.send(req.signedCookies.test);
})
```

I have aa

but if I try the /test2 url just after

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.signedCookies.test)
    res.send("test");
})
```

I have undefined

I also have no test cookie in my browser

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to send cookies, you have to set them in the response (`res`).  Changing the value in the *request* (`req`) does nothing.

```
res.cookie('test', 'aa', { signed: true });
```

See the [`res.cookie` docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie).